# Can n different numbers be sorted using radix sort (and counting sort for digits) in Θ(n) time?

Tags: time-complexity, radix-sort, counting-sort

Can n different numbers be sorted using radix sort (and counting sort for digits) in Θ(n) time?

i would say yes. This is because radix sort processes the digits of the numbers in a fixed number of passes, each taking linear time, resulting in a total time complexity of Θ(n)
have i got this right ? if not then how ?

Comment: *"a fixed number of passes"*: how many is that then? Can you tell us what this fixed number is? Or is it .... not fixed?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no constraint on the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of the input, then: no, the time complexity is *not* Θ().

You write:

> radix sort processes the digits of the numbers in a fixed number of passes

The number of passes is not fixed; it is determined by the input. You don't know upfront how many digits a number in the input might have. Unless you put restrictions on the input, a number might have 100 digits, 1000 digits, ... It is a *variable* determined by the input itself.

As [Wikipedia - Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Complexity_and_performance) puts it:

> Radix sort operates in O() time, where  is the number of keys, and  is the key length.